# Show inline html(comments) with photos fancybox

Tags: fancybox, comments, photo

I am working on a webapp where I need to show comments along with the photo using fancybox. The comments are custom and not from facebook. I am using beta 3 version of fancybox which includes all the features of fancybox 2.3, I hope.

below is the code, I have tried:

```
$("[rel='fancybox-thumb']").fancybox({
    helpers : {
        thumbs : true,
    },
    caption : {
        type : 'inside',
        position: 'right'
    },

    fitToView : false,
    autoSize  : false,
    width     : 600,
    height    : 'auto',


    mouseWheel: false,
     afterLoad: function () {
        if(in_array(media, this.href,false)){
             var orientation = $(this.element).data('orientation'); 
             var width = 640;
             var height = 480;
             if(orientation == 3){
                 var datasetup = '{ "plugins": { "zoomrotate": { "rotate": "180", "zoom": "1.0" } } }';
             }
             else if(orientation == 1){
                 var datasetup = '{ "plugins": { "zoomrotate": { "rotate": "90", "zoom": "1.0" } } }';

             }
             else{
                 var datasetup = '{ "plugins": { "zoomrotate": { "rotate": "360", "zoom": "1.0" } } }';
             }
             this.content ='<video id="parse-video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vid" width="'+width+'" height="'+height+'" data-setup="'+datasetup+'" preload="auto" poster="ajax-loader.gif" autoplay ><source src="'+this.href+'" type='+type+' />' +
                      '<!-- Flash Fallback. Use any flash video player here. Make sure to keep the vjs-flash-fallback class. -->' +
                      '<object id="flash_fallback_1" class="vjs-flash-fallback" width="'+width+'" height="'+height+'" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"' +
                        'data="/players/flowplayer/flowplayer.swf">' +
                        '<param name="movie" value="/players/flowplayer/flowplayer.swf" />' +
                        '<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />' +
                        '<param name="flashvars" value=\'config={"playlist":["' + url + '.png", {"url": '+ this.href + ',"autoPlay":true,"autoBuffering":true}]}\' />' +
                        '<!-- Image Fallback. Typically the same as the poster image. -->' +
                        '<img src="' + url + '.png" width="632" height="15" alt="Poster Image"' +
                         ' title="No video playback capabilities." />' +
                      '</object>' +
                    '</video><div>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</div>' ;


        }
        else{
            //$(".fancybox-inner").css('display','inline-block').wrap('<div style="display: inline-block" id="wrapper"></div>');
            //$('#wrapper').prepend('<div style="display:inline-block" id="content-div">Some content here</div>');
            $(".fancybox-wrap").css('width',$(".fancybox-wrap").width()+200);
        }
    },
    beforeShow: function(){
        console.log($(".fancybox-wrap").width());
        $(".fancybox-wrap").css('visibility','hidden');
        $(".fancybox-wrap").css('width',$(".fancybox-wrap").width()+200);
        $(".fancybox-wrap").append('<div style="width:190px;display:inline-block">this is the comment</div>');
        $(".fancybox-inner").css('display','inline-block');
    },
    afterShow: function(){
        if(in_array(media, this.href,false)){
            var my_video_id = videojs('parse-video-'+i);
            var orientation = $(this.element).data('orientation'); 
            if(orientation == 3){
                my_video_id.zoomrotate({
                    rotate: 180,
                    zoom: 1.0
                });
            }else if(orientation == 1){
                my_video_id.zoomrotate({
                    rotate: 90,
                    zoom: 1.0
                });
            }else{
                my_video_id.zoomrotate({
                    rotate: 360,
                    zoom: 1.0
                });
            }
        }else{

        }


    }
    //'onComplete': function () { $("#fancybox-inner").css({ 'overflow': 'hidden' }); },
    //'onClosed': function () { $("#fancybox-inner").empty(); },
});
```

Also, I am playing videos in fancybox. I am able to show text along with images this way but window resize disturbs the css. many thanks in advance.

Comment: where is your code and how you have tried to get working what you want?

Comment: I have added the code, I am trying.